# Sliding window average of last N non-empty non-blank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

Similar to this question:

[Average of last 7 non-empty non-blank cells in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86897/average-of-last-7-non-empty-non-blank-cells-in-google-sheets)

I'd like a formula to compute a *sliding window* average of the last `N` *non-blank* cells in a column. e.g. For `N = 7`, with the data in column `H`, beginning in row 3:

[image: input & output illustration]

Cells from the input column with no data do not generate a corresponding value in the output column, and they are omitted from the averaging.

The main difference is that the linked question gives you the average of the very last `N` (non-blank) values in the column. Thus as you append new values, the computation updates. It's not a sliding window, and not suitable for filling down.

Comment: What have you tried? What errors?

Comment: @JanDoggen, I tried lots of things, until I finally came up with the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

For sliding window size `N=7`, with data starting in `H3`,

`=if(and(len(H3)>0,count(H$3:H3)>=7),average(indirect("H" & large(filter(row(H$3:H3), len(H$3:H3)), 7) & ":H" & row (H3))),"")`

### Explanation

Here it is repeated with indentation, for reference in the following explanation.

```
if
(
  and
  (
    len(H3)>0,
    count(H$3:H3)>=7
  ),
  average
  (
    indirect
    (
      "H" &
      large(filter(row(H$3:H3), len(H$3:H3)), 7) &
      ":H" &
      row (H3)
    )
  ),
  ""
)
```

- The `$` fixes rows, so that as you fill down, `H$3:H3` ranges become `H$3:H4`, `H$3:H5`, ... `H$3:H9`, `H$3:H10`, etc.
- `filter(row(...), len(...))` returns an array that consists of the row numbers of the nonempty entries in the given range.
- `large(..., 7)` picks the 7th largest number from this array: this is the row number where you want to start averaging.
- `indirect("H" & ... & ":H" ...)` forms the range for averaging, e.g., `H9:H15` if the output of preceding computation was 15.

  - Unlike the linked answer, we append the `row` so that the range ends at the current row (for the sliding window), instead of going all the way to the bottom.
- Finally, `average` does the average. You could put other aggregate functions here, too.
- We replace the linked answer's `iferror()` with the surrounding `if(and(len(H3)>0,count(H$3:H3)>=7), ..., "")`. This makes it only generate an output value if the cell has a value (`len()>0`), and if there have been at least 7 non-empty data points (`count(...)>=7`).

  - Using `len()>0` instead of `isblank()` makes it exclude cells with formulas that generate no output.
  - Alternatively, omit the `and()` and `count()`, and just don't paste the formula into the first `N-1` cells in the output column. Then you'd have

    ```
    =if(len(H3)>0,average(indirect("H" & large(filter(row(H$3:H3), len(H$3:H3)), 7) & ":H" & row (H3))),"")
    ```

    (Or use that simplified formula, and begin output at the first input row, knowing that the first `N-1` values are computed over the smaller ranges.)

#### Fill Over

If you copy the formula to a horizontally-adjacent column, and want it to look at input data from an also horizontally-adjacent column (`I`), you'll have to replace the literal (quoted) `H`s with `I`s.

Alternatively, you can complicate the formula a bit to automate this, using a formula such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter/22129496#22129496) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/convert-column-index-into-corresponding-column-letter/30777592#30777592). Then you'd have

`=if(and(len(H3)>0,count(H$3:H3)>=7),average(indirect(regexextract(address(1, column(H$1)), "[A-Z]+") & large(filter(row(H$3:H3), len(H$3:H3)), 7) & ":" & regexextract(address(1, column(H$1)), "[A-Z]+") & row (H3))),"")`